# how i can install openedx in windows macheen?

Tags: python, windows, pip, openedx

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [12 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\tutorlicense
copying tutorlicense\plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\tutorlicense
copying tutorlicense_*about*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\tutorlicense
copying tutorlicense_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\tutorlicense
running build_ext
building 'tutorlicense.cmd' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tutor-license
Running setup.py clean for tutor-license
Failed to build tutor-license
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tutor-license, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i want install openedx in window macheen when i run command pip install "tutor[full]"
this error ocur

Answer (score 1):

that error is saying that "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required". Have you already tried to install the microsoft build tools?

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ (Got the link from your topic)

I have them installed and with an empty virtual environment i'm able to run

```
pip install tutor[full]
```

Without any problem